# Locating a Sunni mosque in Worcestershire

Tags: uk, religion, islam, mosques

I am hosting a group of Saudi Arabians in Worcestershire, UK.  I am trying to locate a suitable mosque (Sunni based) that they can attend but I am struggling to find an appropriate one using the internet.  Can anyone provide guidance on how to locate a suitable mosque that will satisfy their needs?

Comment: Are you in the UK or have UK contacts ? The city of Worcester has a website with a contact form. A quick google maps search of mosque near Worcestershire UK shows one mosque with contact info (Kidderminster Mosque). I can't tell if they're Sunni or not, but you can call them.

Comment: I think migrating this here was a poor decision. It would be better back at Islam. However Google does provide a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

A site called "Salatomatic", which is the first result retrieved by Google (after StackExchange) provides a [list of 7 Sunni mosques in Worcestershire](http://www.salatomatic.com/c/Worcestershire+348).